# Store Mysql rows in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I was wondering how I can store values in an Array, because I can just `echo` the `$row['Name']`, but if I want to store multiple values in array I get nothing.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbname . " WHERE id ='$id'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $thisArray[] = array( $row['Name'],$row['accountNumber']);
}

echo $thisArray[0];
```

Comment: you did not declared the array. so, first declared the array like this `$thisArray =array(); ` before start of the loop and use `print_r`

Comment: `$thisArray[0]` is itself an array, so you should use `print_r($thisArray[0]);`

Comment: Agreed with @NigelRen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just want to load the results of a SQL statement into an array, you can use `mysqli_fetch_all()` and just fetch the columns you need.

When outputing the results, arrays should be output with something like `print_r()`...

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT Name,accountNumber FROM " . $dbname . " WHERE id ='$id'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$thisArray = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r( $thisArray[0]);
```

**Update:** 
If you want to re-arrange the array to key by one of the columns, `array_column()` can do this...

```
$thisArray = array_column($thisArray, 'accountNumber', 'Name');
```

Comment: much better solution rather than other-one.+1

Comment: I am getting a result : Array ( [Name] => Kristiqn [accountNumber] => 0 ). How can I get just the value (Kristiqn and 0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your array outside of the loop first and when you echo it you don't need to specify a key except if you need a specific key.
Based on your code above:

```
$thisArray = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thisArray[] = [
        $row['Name'],
        $row['accountNumber']
    ];
}

echo $thisArray;
```